# Nodejs on ubuntu 16.04 - Error when running script in console

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I installed nodejs on ubuntu and tried to run my first application following to this:

Step 1:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

I run an apache though.

hello.js (saved in /var/www/html/nodejs/) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World! Node.js is working correctly!\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

When I enter in the browser http://localhost:8080/ I get:

```
Hello World! Node.js is working correctly!
```

But when I want to run it in the console I get this:

```
sven@sven-MS-7464:~$ node /var/www/html/nodejs/hello.js
Server running at http://localhost:8080/
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/nodejs/hello.js:6:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Why can I not run it? What do I need to do?

```
$ node -v
v8.9.4
$ nodejs -v
v8.9.4
$ npm -v
5.6.0

$ sudo npm config get proxy
null
$ sudo npm config
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm config set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm config get [<key>]
npm ERR! npm config delete <key>
npm ERR! npm config list [--json]
npm ERR! npm config edit
npm ERR! npm set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm get [<key>]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! alias: c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you have run the application previously with `pm2` according to the provided link:

Firstly stop the app using `pm2 stop <your_app_name>`

Then run on console `node <app_name>`

Comment: Yes ... stopping pm2 and then run it in the console work. ... and vice versa. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are confused.

If you could access it in the browser then your node application was running correctly.

When you then try to run it on the console, the error message is telling you that it's already running!

What are you expecting?

Comment: Yes I'm confused :-) ... so this is normal bahaviour?

Comment: Yep. You've created a script that can self execute when hit by a browser (by using the `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs` prefix. So hitting it with the browser started the script, which is a long-running web-server (i.e. it keeps on running till you kill it). Then when you tried to run it from the command line it was already running, so it informed you of that with `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080` (i.e. port 8080 is already in use).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. First time trying nodejs ... so still a lot to learn I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your last node process thus making port 8080 blocked (indicated by the `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080` message).
To free it use `killall node` and run your script again.